# I need a help to understand this code

Tags: java

Actually, this is the first time I see a code like this:

```
class A
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        outer : for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<10;j++)
            {
                if(j > i)
                {
                    System.out.println();
                    continue outer;
                }
                System.out.print("  "  +( i *j ));
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

two lines I don't understand:

```
outer : for(int i=0;i<10;i++) // this seems similar to 'for each'?

continue outer; // I know that 'continue' will break the loop and continue the next turn, but what will do in this situaton?
```

Comment: Why the downvote? There are no stupid questions, only stupid teachers.

Comment: @Aaron: I think there *are* stupid questions, but I don't think this is one of them.

Comment: This kinda code is what happens when you translate legacy C into Java and are afraid to touch anything...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
outer : for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
```

defines a label for the outer loop, called `outer`

```
continue outer;
```

means, go to next iteration of the loop labeled `outer`

Answer (score 10):

The `outer:` part is a label. It's basically labelling the loop. The loop itself works just as normal.

The `continue outer;` means "continue back to the start of the body of the loop labelled `outer`" (after incrementing and testing `i` of course). It's sort of like having a `break;` statement to get out of the inner loop, and then immediately having a normal `continue;` statement to continue with the next step of the outer loop.

Answer (score 3):

`outer` is a label, when `continue outer;` is called, the code will jump to the `outer` label and continue from there.  The reason behind it in this case is that the coder wants to exit the inner loop when `j>i` and continue the outer loop.

Comment: oh great, first time I know that java has this feature ... Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

from the java documentation:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Outer: is a label,  instead of continuing the inner loop, you are continuing the outer loop by specifying the label

See also http://www.janeg.ca/scjp/flow/labels.html

Answer (score 1):

`outer` is a label, and  `continue outer` basically does a `goto` but continues in the loop rather than starting it again.

Answer (score 1):

`outer:` defines a label "outer" which you can use in `break` and `continue`. It's only allowed in front of loop constructs (`for`, `while`, `do`).

So `continue outer` means "continue with the outer loop" or "apply the `continue` to the loop with the matching label".